# What is a good naming convention for Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, naming-conventions

I'm pretty much a noob with Unity. As a c++ programmer, the naming conventions in Unity bothers me a little. And having OCD ontop of that makes me go crazy ;)

The objects has say a property `Transform` which again has a property `Position`.
But these properties must be accessed by writing `transform.position` in the code using lower case. This is not very intuitive to me. So I wonder how I can look at it in order to more easily avoid complications. And what conventions I should use to be able to tell everything appart by taking a quick look at the variables.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Unity convention is actually rather simple: everything is Pascal-cased, types (classes, structs, enums) and methods start with upper-case, fields and properties with lower-case. Enum values in upper-case, constants in lower-case (usually).
So `ClassName`, `MethodName`, `myField`, `myProperty { get; set; }`, `MyEnum.CaseA`... that's it.

As for your example, `Transform` is a class, whereas `transform` is an accessor to the instance of `Transform` in that particular GameObject/Component.
Also, `Transform` doesn't have a `Position` property, it has a `position` property (always lower-case).

This is more or less based on C#'s conventions and the standard .NET library (MS has [very](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx) [precise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) about it), except standard .NET uses UpperCase for public/protected methods AND properties, and lower-case for private (again, usually; what's private is more left to the taste of the coder I think).

As a side-note, with any codebase, in any language, the best way is ALWAYS to follow the existing convention. Every seasoned programmer will tell you this. I understand about OCD, believe me, but in this case I suggest you let it go.
There are very little objective arguments as to why a convention would be better than another (by definition a convention is arbitrary), and even if there was, the absolute worse thing you can do is mix several conventions, because then you have 0 convention at all and never know what to expect.

At least C# tries to standardize; I've worked on several C++ codebases and I fail to see a common denominator: `UpperCaseClassNames`, `lowerCaseClassNames`, `underscore_separated`, `tClassName`, `ENUMS_IN_UPPER`, or not... it's rarely consistent, so the less you mix the better.

Comment: I just think it is a little misleading still when the Inspector panel display it differently than it should be called in the code.

Comment: The inspector panel just attempts to make the class/property names look more human readable.  I don't understand how this could cause a problem. The naming conventions used by Unity (and/or C#) are pretty standard and quite intuitive as far as I can tell... I think you'll get used to them pretty quickly if you make an attempt to understand them.

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant by "Position"... yes, the inspector inserts spaces between words (== capital letters); it also removes any leading m_, things like that.
This process is called "nicifying": http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ObjectNames.NicifyVariableName.html
The inspector is meant for everyone, not only programmers; camel casing is historically just a hack because compilers don't like spaces... but humans do! Spaces are always more readable than camel-case and underscores.

Comment: I think one problem is that mixing Unity projects with other (non-Unity) libraries you always end up mixing them up - that is for me the part that annoys me :) you are not able to keep everything consistent.

Comment: This answer is not correct and actually goes against their eBooks recommendation. Their actual recommendations are that variable names that are Public, should be PascalCase, properties should be PascalCase and private variables should be camelCase prefixed with an underscore. They make a specific point about this and also state that it is based on the Microsoft C# recommendations which say the same exact thing.

Comment: Can't accept `Time.deltatime` in this form, why not `Time.DeltaTime`!!!!My OCD, it's so painful!

Comment: I have a dream, a dream of a day where all their camelCase properties are obsoleted and fresh PascalCase properties added. It'd add quite some bloat in the interim though :) Or they could do a Godot 4 and just nuke all the old names and get you to figure out the new ones.